# Drupal OpenLayers how to solve : The layer cannot be reprojected to the map projection: EPSG:

Tags: drupal-7, openlayers, projection

Here is my adventure. [On this page](http://www.ithaka.im/nl/route) I would like to display our bicycle route.

I am using in drupal 7:

- Openlayers 7.x-2.0-beta3
- OpenLayers KML Layer 7.x-1.0-beta1 (I'm not sure if I need this module as well)
- layer: `openlayers_kml_example` with the source a url to a file.
- map : `example_kml` Example KML Map

The result is that the layer is displayed very very small on the big map. So if you zoom in to the airplane eventually you can see the track.

Map Projection set to 3857
Display Map Projection set to 4326 (the KML is made with Google earth. I think not important as there is no interaction only displaying.
LAYER SPECIFIC OPTIONS FOR KM extract styles and attributes ON. 
If I put tracks on then I will miss the nice airplane icon.

I keep getting the same logs and of course no display on the page:

```
MESSAGE The layer cannot be reprojected to the map projection: EPSG:
MESSAGE Notice: Undefined variable: map in openlayers_layer_sanity_check() (line 399
MESSAGE Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in openlayers_layer_sanity_check()
```

As it is not nice for people to think that I'm cycling constantly in water I would like to solve it :-)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Update openlayers to latest version including the needed dependencies and run updates. 
Reset layer and map to default and then apply new source for kml file. 
Ready :-)

Comment: Are you saying that is a solution? If so, could you mark as fixed. Cool page, btw, I am a cyclist and love Africa.

Comment: Yes that is the solution.

Comment: I cannot set it to  fixed because there is now answer. I cannot add a answer because I'm new on this system and have no points or so..

Comment: OK, I can put in an answer for you, that might help others. Do you know what version of OpenLayers corresponds to Drupal version 7.x? I think it is because EPSG:3857 is quite recent -- it used to be called 900913.

Answer (score 0):

John is correct in describing the issues but here is the solution :-)

Update drupal module openlayers to the latest version, currently 7.x-2.0-beta9.
Take care of the needed dependencies.

I reset all my layers and maps to the orginial and then adjusted the source of the kml layer to a file.

Comment: Are you not allowed to accept your own answer? It is good to mark things as closed, if you can.